# How to retrieve data from a form ( type = "text" ) and store in database in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I want to retrieve data for a user's comment using a form but I'm not too sure how to do that even after looking at the laravel documentation and videos.

my "CommentsController" code snipit looks like this

```
public function submitComment(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'comment'=> 'required|max:500'
        ]);

        $comment= new Comments;
        $comment->comments=$request->input->('comment');


         DB::table('comments')->insert(
    array('user_id'=>1,
         'post_id'=>1,
         'comment'=> $comment)
);
```

, my form snipit looks like this

```
<?php


        echo '<form method="POST" action="comments"> ';
        echo '<input name="comment" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" style="width:200px; height:50px;" placeholder="Type Here">';
        echo '<input type="submit">' ;
        echo '</form>';



        ?>
```

and my table in the database looks like this

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('comments');
    $table->timestamps();

    //Foreign Keys
    $table->foreign('post_id')
        ->references('id')->on('posts')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$comment->comments=$request->input->('comment');
```

to

```
$comment->comments  =$request->comment;
```

Basically you can get a input by *$request->formName*

I also tent to create new records like

```
$record = Comment::create([ 'user_id' => $userId, 'post_id' => $postId, 'comments' => $request->comments]);
```

But you would need to create a model to do so like that.

```
php artisan make:model Comment
```